# How to avoid data discrepancy between multiple parties with dependent financial interests?

Tags: authentication, data-validation

#### Generalized problem

say there are 2 companies/parties A and B (there may be more) and there is an event E which is recorded by both A and B.

Let's say the occurrences of event E according to A is 'E by A' and according to B is 'E by B'.

B has to pay to A per event E ('some rate' multiplied by 'occurrences of E')

So assuming bad faith:

- A wants to show that 'E by A' is more than the actual value
- B wants to show that 'E by B' is less than the actual value

**How to make sure that the data is authentic and no one is cheating?**

#### Specific problem

Say there is an advertising company A and another company B that hires A to manage their ads for them and B agrees to pay per click on their ad, shown by A.
If A records the clicks on their system **how to make sure that A is not exaggerating the number of clicks?**

And if B is recording, then **how to make sure that B is not understating the number of clicks?**

And if both are recording, then both problems apply.

#### My thoughts

I was thinking is there some cryptographic way to solve this problem. I understand that if they hire a 3rd neutral company to record the clicks it would be OK? but what if I don't want a 3rd party?

Answer (score 1):

Cryptography is not going to be of use. What you have is a matter of objective assurance. How does one party assure the other that the data is accurate and that it could not possibly be any different? Cryptographically, I could assert anything. What you are trying to battle is a "conflict of interest".

3rd parties who do not have an interest in one outcome or another is the typical way this is handled. An uninterested observer makes the assertion. Both parties are bound to the observer's assertion.

Comment: then how do online ad services assure their clients that a customer is visiting their website because of an ad that they showed? e.g. [google ads](https://ads.google.com/home/pricing/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, an answer will be zero-knowledge Proof.

> The classic example of a zero-knowledge proof involves two individuals: Peggy and Victor. Peggy knows the password to a secret
> door located inside a circular cave Victor would like to buy the
> password from Peggy, but he wants Peggy to prove that she knows the
> password before paying her for it. Peggy doesn’t want to tell Victor
> the password for fear that he won’t pay later. The zero-knowledge
> proof can solve their dilemma.

(copied from official CISSP guide 8th edition)

Please refer to the following link for more details
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof

Comment: Could you elaborate how zero-knowledge proof could be used in the specific problem?

Comment: @Manik your question is too broad to answer here. Try to understand, through this link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOKh7WQgwpw&feature=emb_logo

Comment: @Infra um, you are proposing this concept as a solution. It is not too broad to ask how you propose to apply it, even conceptually, to the stated problem ... I understand zero-knowledge proof, and it is difficult to see how it could apply ...